# How to enable Windows 10 notification and action center

Tags: windows-10, notifications

I am not sure but it looks that i disabled windows 10 notifications permanently. I can't receive popups at all. All related settings are ok in windows Setting but still not able to receive notifications. Please help me.

Comment: What are the related settings?

Answer (score 0):

1.If your action center cannot receive any notifications， because we may relate to background APP feature of windows 10.
we can follow these steps to turn on this feature:
a. open the settings app
b.go to privacy - background apps under App permissions
c.On the right, ensure that you have the option Let apps run in the background enabled.
d.If the option is disabled, you should enable it.

2.However, if the mentioned option is enabled, but the Action Center notifications are still broken, you should try the following.

Open Settings.
Go to Privacy -> Background apps.
Turn off the option  Let apps run in the background.
Restart Windows 10.
After restarting your PC, open Settings again and enable the mentioned option.
Restart the operating system.
This sequence should restore notifications.

Best regards,

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did everything you said but still i can not receive notifications. I need notification when i compile node packages with cmd.